# Referencing another class as an Instance Variable?

Tags: java, class, methods

I am looking for some help with utilizing methods from another class in Java. I have created a class that has some getter and setter methods. The getter method contains a switch statement that has a passed in parameter "i" that determines the case of the switch statement.

Now in my main program I am looking to use that class method, but for some reason I am getting a java.lang.nullpointerexception.

The code in my main program looks like this:

```
public class Hangman extends ConsoleProgram {

    public void run() {

        String name = word.getWord(5);

        println(name);
    }



    /* Private Instance Variable */
    private HangmanLexicon word; // Creates a new lexicon from the HangmanLexicon class.
    private RandomGenerator rgen = RandomGenerator.getInstance(); // Creates a new random generator instance.
```

}

So as you can tell I created the private ivar, but for some reason it does not work. Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you show `word` is never given a value so it will be `null`

You might need something like:

```
 private HangmanLexicon word = new HangmanLexicon();
```

Or you might need to get a HangmanLexicon object to put in your instance variable some other way.

*Note* If you are doing this for a Stanford CS class (or similar university class) I found the source of the HangmanLexicon online by searching. The line above would work *if AND ONLY IF that is the same code as what I found.*

Comment: Thank you very much for that! I do understand the fact that I need to assign a variable a value, but I was not sure what value to assign. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Creating the variable us not enough: you have to assign something to it, too.

```
private HangmanLexicon word = /*put something here*/;
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back, but what do I put as the value for a class? It doesn't necessarily have a defined type of String, int, etc. So what value would I assign to it?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialized the `word` variable. So it has the default value: null. And calling a method on a null object cause a NullPointerException.

Read a good book about Java, or the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html). This is basic stuff you need to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for `NullPointerException` occurs because word has no value assigned. You must assign value to `word` first before using it to call the method `getWord(5)`;

```
private HangmanLexicon word;
                        ^
```

initialize or assign  word like this instead as follows

```
private HangmanLexicon word=new HangmanLexicon();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that! I knew that I had to initialize the variable, but I did not know what to write down as the value. Thanks!

Comment: you mean value for word? word is an instance of class `HangmanLexican`, by using word you could call different methods of the class